# Store Arabic and English in Html input

Tags: html, sql-server, input, arabic, right-to-left

I have a problem when i want to store Arabic and English characters in one input in Sql Server table. For example i want to store this sentence like it is written: `Python لغة البرمجة` but it is stored like this in the Sql server table : `لغة البرمجة Python`.

I used dir: rtl in the input but it still displays in the same way.

```
<input asp-for="DesignationAR" class="form-control" dir="rtl" />
```

So how to save Arabic and English in one input with RightToLeft direction?

Comment: You're basically want us to address two problems: 1. Storage in your SQL server. 2. Direction of input. I think your question stands a much better chance of getting an useful answer if you concentrate on one of these question, because they seem completely unrelated.

Comment: No the direction in the input is RTL and this is what i want, the problem is only in the storage in Sql server

Comment: I probably don't understand this problem, but I must not be the only one. I [made four inputs](https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/yLROrBm), using both strings from your question, either with `dir: rtl` or not. That didn't help me, but I did see that the cursor moves back and forth over the text. This probably has to do with the [Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/inline-bidi-markup/uba-basics). Do you use unicode in your database?

Comment: I want to write the arabic word لغة البرمجة  first then space then the english word Python , the direction is RTL . in the input with the RTL direction it is written as i want but when i save to sql server it is not saved as i want , it is saved like this: لغة البرمجة Python

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? Very old versions might cause a problem. I also found [this question about collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/902613/sql-collation-that-supports-both-english-and-arabi). I did note that you didn't answer my question about this in my previous comment.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.